# Вызов определённой функции при получении переданного через GET или POST

Tags: php

В html имеется 3 button. У каждой своя форма отправки с одним и тем же именем, но с разным значением.

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="button1">
        <input type="submit" value="Кнопка 1">
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="button2">
        <input type="submit" value="Кнопка 2">
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="button3">
        <input type="submit" value="Кнопка 3">
</form>
```

В контроллере имеются 3 функции с аналогичными именами отправляемых значений:

```
function button1();
function button2();
function button3();
```

Каким образом при чтении POST запроса можно вызвать функцию, имя которой идентично полученному значению `$_POST['action']`?

Comment: а возложить это всё на js?

Comment: Вспомнился [Twitto](http://twitto.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$_POST['action']();
```

Но лучше так не делать, самый минимум это надо проверять есть/нет данной переменной, есть/нет такой функции, можно ли выполнять, ну и т.д.

Думаю, если вы идете похожим путем, то стоит задуматься, все ли правильно вы делаете, и возможно стоит выбрать другой путь.

Comment: Нашёл то, что искал) call_user_func() Но всё равно, спасибо за ответ)